# Where does the Ben Ish Hai speak about the spread of Kabbalah in Od Yosef Hai

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ben-ish-chai

I recall once hearing that the Ben Ish Hai in Od Yosef Hai proves that Kabbalah is true by showing that there are mysterious things in the world that can only be explained by Kabbalah. He also mentions how the wisdom of Kabbalah spread everywhere.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Happens to be he makes that point about some things only being explainable by Kabbalah in many places. I would be interested in seeing this source you're seeking, too, though.